# serial.println(String) prints "#" instead of the string

Tags: c, arduino, println

i'm just trying to recieve a string using a serial and to send this string back. So when i send a string to an arduino over a serial the arduino should automaticly send this string back.

i created this code:

```
String test;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(2);
  test = "null";
}

void loop(){
  if(Serial.available()){
    test = Serial.readString();
  }
  Serial.println(test);
}
```

I guess it is not that difficult to understand. However now the arduino will always print a "#" instead of the variable test. My connected serial device is a bluetooth modul. (hc-06)

What did i do wrong?

Thank you!

(i also ran this code in the arduino emulator 123D Circuits. There it worked just fine)

Comment: What is the 'String' type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change your code. Move `println` into `if` statement.

Try increase timeout interval, 2ms is not enough, good value (at 9600) lies above 10ms. Theoretically timeout should be at least 3.5 characters long and for current speed this equals ~0,4 ms. But in practice higher values are used.

```
String test;
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(10);// or more
  test = "null";
}
void loop(){
  if(Serial.available()){
    test = Serial.readString();
    Serial.println(test);// moved into if
  }
}
```

---

Update: Another simple solution to return characters back looks like:

```
void loop(){
      if(Serial.available()) Serial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

---

Update 2: Had similar issue with BLE module HM10 (clone, not official). It was sending about 15 dummy bytes prior to any array. And i didn't solve it. But if weired bytes always the same you can make a simple trick using [String.remove()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringRemove):

```
if(Serial.available()){
        test = Serial.readString();
        test.remove(0,5);
        // test.remove - add code to remove last character
        Serial.println(test);
 }
```

Also try another terminal.

Comment: Sory, not clear: you receive what you send or not? Or you have additional string prior to expected.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't complete the answer. I mean if i send "hello" it will return "*12|99|99|hello#". So the value of the test variable is there however there are also these weired characters.

Comment: Try code from update, let me know if you will receive weired characters.

Comment: still getting the same :(

Comment: Good. This means that you are *sending* those characters, what terminal do you use?

Comment: i use a bluetooth modul that is connected to the reveicer and transmitter pin. I powered it up with the 5v pin. For sending the data to the bluetooth modul i use an android phone with an app called "ArduDroid" (by TechBitar)

Comment: posted update if count of redundant bytes always same